# How to find correct end point of an arc from given start point, center point, start angle and radius?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, tangent-line, arc-length

I want to find correct end point of an arc.
I have Arc start point, arc start angle, center point of arc, radius of arc. Please refer below image.

[image]

I want to draw arc from point **a** to **d**. But I don't have end point **d**. so I am not able to draw correct arc. My goal is to find correct end point. I have end point **b** which is incorrect.

Comment: Please clarify, do you need to make a geometric (i.e. ruler and compass) construction or are you looking for an algebraic solution? If the alter, check out [Rotation Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), and consider that the mean point is made for you to know if you should rotate clockwise or counter-clockwise.

Comment: Hi, there needs to be some additional information about the end point - as it is, it can be anywhere on the circle.

Comment: I have updated my question @TodorMarkov

Comment: As Arthur pointed out in the comments, you still haven't provided enough information. As things stand, any point on the circle is fully consistent with all the information provided - there's no way to narrow it down. Perhaps you should tell us the full story of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If $c$ is the origin, then you just want to rotate $a$ by an angle of $\sigma$ about the origin, and that's a well-known transformation:
$$
d_x = a_x\cos(\sigma) - a_y\sin(\sigma)\\
d_y = a_x\sin(\sigma) + a_y\cos(\sigma)
$$
If $c$ is *not* the origin, then we need to move everything so that it is at the origin, rotate there, and then move back. The final formula then becomes
$$
d_x = (a_x - c_x)\cos(\sigma) - (a_y-c_y)\sin(\sigma) + c_x\\
d_y = (a_x-c_x)\sin(\sigma) + (a_y - c_y)\cos(\sigma) + c_y
$$

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I don't have "σ", only start angle is known. @Arthur

Comment: @Java-Dev I missed that, sorry. However, the way I see it, then, is that you don't have any information at all that lets us say anything about where the end point is. We only know the starting point and the center point.

Comment: I have updated my question @Arthur

Comment: @Java-Dev The only information you've included is the coordinates of a new, not really related point $b$. That doesn't help at all. We still have no new information that helps to pin down $d$.

Comment: "β" and "θ" is also known. @Arthur

Comment: @Java-Dev I could in theory figure them out from the coordinates of $a,b,c$ anyways. The only thing you seem to know about $d$ is the distance from $c$, and that's just not enough.